# Wrong displayed image name in image viewer python 3.5

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When i open an image in image viewer the displayed image name is wrong (not the same as loaded image). Orginal image = 'image.PNG', name in image viewer='tmpy4uvijg0.BMP' (the new name always changeds, see in image below)

```
from PIL import Image
imName='image.PNG'
try:
    with Image.open(imName) as im:
        print(imName)
        im.show()
except IOError:
    pass
```

[image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfknn.png)
[new image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro6cM.png)

What do i wrong? Why is the name not the same?

Comment: it seems PIL has to convert PNG to BMP before it can display.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the `show` method save the image to a temporary file, as say in the documentation:

> Displays this image. This method is mainly intended for
>           debugging purposes.
>
> On Unix platforms, this method saves the image to a temporary
>           PPM file, and calls the **xv** utility.
>
> On Windows, it saves the image to a temporary BMP file, and uses
>           the standard BMP display utility to show it (usually Paint).
>
> :param title: Optional title to use for the image window,
>              where possible.
>
> :param command: command used to show the image

You can try to change the title by passing a string in parameter to show.